# WP Как создать пагинацию для комментариев по странично?

Tags: wordpress, pagination, комментарии, get-query-var

Необходимо что б на странице кастомного типа записи выводилась кастомная форма отображения списка комментариев с пагинацией. На других типах записи используеться пагинация других видов, для страниц, поэтому пишем в отдельном шаблоне миную `comments.php`

Благодаря вот этой статье [get_query_var()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_query_var) Был написан вот такой код с параметрами cpage
`custom-comments-template.php`

```
<?php if (post_password_required()) {
    return;
}
$per_page = 4;

$page = get_query_var('cpage') ?: 1;

?>
<div id="comments" class="company-rewiew-list">
    <h1>Per page = <?php echo $per_page?></h1>
    <h2>Page - <?php echo $page?></h2>
    <?php

    wp_list_comments(array(
        'type' => 'comment',
        'reverse_top_level' => false, // Отключите сортировку родительских комментариев от старых к новым
        'reverse_children' => false, // Включите сортировку ответов на родительские комментарии от новых к старым
        'callback' => 'reviews_theme_comment',
        'per_page' => $per_page,
        'cpage' => $page,
    )); ?>
</div>

<?php

/// Pagination
if ($per_page > 1){
    $custom_pagination_template = locate_template('template-parts/custom-comments-pagination.php');
    if ($custom_pagination_template) {
        include $custom_pagination_template;
    }
}

?>
```

Сам же файл пагинации `custom-comments-pagination.php` выглядит так

```
<div class="company-rewiew-pagination">
    <?php

    $args = array(
        'post_id' => get_the_ID(), // Идентификатор текущего поста
        'parent' => 0, // Только родительские комментарии
        'count' => true, // Запрос для получения количества комментариев
    );
    $top_level_comments_count = get_comments($args);
    $max_pages = ceil($top_level_comments_count / $per_page);

    $args = array(
        'screen_reader_text' => __('Comments navigation'),
        'aria_label' => __('Comments'),
        'class' => 'comments-pagination',
        'base' => add_query_arg('cpage', '%#%'),
        'format' => '',
        'total' => $max_pages,
        'current' => $page,
        'add_fragment' => '',
        'prev_text' => '❮',
        'next_text' => '❯',
        'type' => 'list',
    );
    echo get_the_comments_pagination($args);
    ?>
</div>

<p>Page value <?php echo $page; ?></p>
<p>Max Pages  <?php echo $max_pages; ?></p>
<p>$top_level_comments_count  <?php echo $top_level_comments_count; ?></p>
```

Для теста создал пост к которому добавил 9 комментариев верхнего уровня и 1 второго.
Проблема в том, что меня на первом входе брасает на "5 страницу" (хотя если у меня 9 комментариев на странице и задаю $per_page = 4; то должно быть максимум 3 и начинать должно с 1 страницы...), откуда это ?

[image: пагинация комментариев]

Я думаю, что моя ошибка где-то в не правильном задавании
`$page = get_query_var('cpage') ?: 1;` пробовал и так `$page = max(1, get_query_var('cpage'));` но не помогло. Не могу понять, из документации это вроде как динамическое значение и оно должно быть разным.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка ? (Почиму меня бросает на 5 страницу, и комментарии отображаються с конца списка)